# Disabling pre-chat programmatically for snap-in chat

Tags: liveagent

I am trying to integrate snap-in chat into our corporate website, and there are two use-cases that I am trying to support:

- Enable pre-chat when visitor hasn't login/created-account with us
- Disable pre-chat when they are already login

According to the documentation, there is a setting that does that:

```
embedded_svc.settings.initialInteractionState
// Enable pre-chat with PRECHAT, disable with WAITING
```

I have tried using either value (and also made sure that is being done before invoking init() function on embedded_svc). However, it doesn't change the behavior - it always rely on what is being configured at the deployment level.

Has anyone able to alter the prechat behavior with the above setting?

Last note: I am using version 22 of embedded_svc.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, I filed a ticket with Salesforce at that time, and they said the documentation was incorrect - the feature wasn't available at all.